# Looping through documents in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to loop through the variable 'docs' which is a cell array that holds strings, i need to make a for loop that colllects the terms in a cell array and then uses command 'lower' and unique to create a dictionary.

Here is the code i've tried sp far and i just get errors

```
docsLength = length(docs);

for C = 1:docsLength
   list = tokenize(docs, ' .,-');
   Mylist = [list;C];
end
```

I get these errors

```
Error using textscan
First input must be of type double or string.
Error in tokenize (line 3)
    C = textscan(str,'%s','MultipleDelimsAsOne',1,'delimiter',delimiters);
Error in tk (line 4)
   list = tokenize(docs, ' .,-');
```

Comment: Can you specify the error you get?

Comment: Also, which variable type is `docs`? what does it contain exactly?

Comment: its a cell array that contains short documents

Comment: maybe the reason is that You are trying to send the whole cell 'docs' to the tokenize method? Try docs{C} which should send a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generically,  if you get an "must be of type" error, that means you are passing the wrong sort of input to a function. In this case you should look at the point in your code where this is taking place (here, in `tokenize` when `textscan` is called), and doublecheck that the input going in is what you expect it to be.

As `tokenize` is not a MATLAB builtin function, unless you show us that code we can't say what those inputs should be. However, as akfaz mentioned in comments, it is likely that you want to pass `docs{C}` (a string) to `tokenize` instead of `docs` (a cell array).  Otherwise, there's no point in having a loop as it just repeatedly passes the same input, `docs`, into the function.

There are additional problems with the loop:

`Mylist = [list; C];` will be overwritten each loop to consist of the latest version of `list` plus `C`, which is just a number (the index of the loop).  Depending on what the output of `tokenize` looks like, `Mylist = [Mylist; list]` *may* work but you should initialise `Mylist` first.

```
Mylist = [];

for C = 1:length(docs)
   list = tokenize(docs{C}, ' .,-');
   Mylist = [Mylist; list];
end
```